# Add maven dependency to Android Studio gradle

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Just trying Android Studio & Gradle and I want to add Roboguice to my Project, this is my `build.gradle`:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.8.+'

    }
}



allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.roboguice:roboguice:2.0'
}
```

gives me

```
Gradle 'TestApp' project refresh failed:
         Build script error, unsupported Gradle DSL method found: 'compile()'!
```

I tried to move the line

```
compile 'org.roboguice:roboguice:2.0'
```

within the `dependencies` in `buildscript` but that also failed.

How is this done correctly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.roboguice:roboguice:2.0'
}
```

[image]Move this part from build.gradle in root (top level build file) to build.gradle in your module

Comment: Any explanation for that?

Comment: @XtremeBiker You have to add your dependencies in your module, not in the top level file.